# how to handle hanged application in test partner

Tags: vbscript, microfocus

I am new to Microsoft TestPartner automation tool, while I am running scripts of my windows application, after some time the application is hanging, Is there any way to handle this kind of situations in Test partner

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are asking. But windbg tries to analyse hangs.

!analyze
The !analyze extension displays information about the current exception or bug check.

User-Mode

```
!analyze [-v] [-f | -hang] [-D BucketID] 
!analyze -c [-load KnownIssuesFile | -unload | -help ]
```

Kernel-Mode

```
!analyze [-v] [-f | -hang] [-D BucketID] 
!analyze -c [-load KnownIssuesFile | -unload | -help ]
!analyze -show BugCheckCode [BugParameters]
```

Parameters

```
-v
```

Displays verbose output.

```
-f
```

Generates the !analyze exception output. Use this parameter to see an exception analysis even when the debugger does not detect an exception.

```
-hang
```

Generates !analyze hung-application output. Use this parameter when the target has experienced a bug check or exception, but an analysis of why an application hung is more relevant to your problem. In kernel mode, !analyze -hang investigates locks that the system holds and then scans the DPC queue chain. In user mode, !analyze -hang analyzes the thread stack to determine whether any threads are blocking other threads.

Before you run this extension in user mode, consider changing the current thread to the thread that you think has stopped responding (that is, hung), because the exception might have changed the current thread to a different one.

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called Symbols in C:\

Start Windbg. File menu - Symbol File Path and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

```
windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat
```

You can press `F12` to stop it and `kb` will show the call stack (`g` continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.

Type `lm` to list loaded modules, `x *!*` to list the symbols and `bp symbolname` to set a breakpoint

If programming in VB6 then this environmental variable `link=/pdb:none` stores the symbols in the dll rather than seperate files. Make sure you compile the program with *No Optimisations* and tick the box for *Create Symbolic Debug Info*. Both on the Compile tab in the Project's Properties.

Also CoClassSyms (microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) can make symbols from type libraries.